# reduce time to load the rows in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hello I have made a project using Parse.com
Here I have a table named "Channel" in this table I have one column named "users" in which I have saved some objectId from ParseUser Table .Now I am fetching the users info from ParseUser of each channels.But it is taking so much time (only for fetching 20 rows from ParseUser Table).The Flow of my app is something like this:

```
"Channel Table"->array= ["345sf3546","wrfc56645","ertrr6356"](objId of ParseUser) ->fetching username and ParseFile from ParseUser Table for a particular channel.
```

The code which I have used is :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (ary_users!=null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < ary_users.size(); i++) {
             Log.d("Objid",">>"+ary_users.get(i));
             final  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
                query.whereEqualTo("objectId",ary_users.get(i));

               try {
            ParseObject p =  query.getFirst();
                 if ((ParseFile)p.get("pic")!=null) {
                 pp = (ParseFile)p.get("pic");
                            }
                else {
                    pp = null;
                            }
                     if (pp!=null) {
                        url = pp.getUrl();
                    }
                     else
                     {
                         url = "";
                     }
             map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("OBJ_ID",p.getObjectId());
            map.put("NAME", p.getString("username"));
            map.put("IMG",url); 

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            ShowList.add(map);
        }   
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here  **ary_users** is Array of users id like this: ["345sf3546","wrfc56645","ertrr6356"].Please help me .I don't know how to reduce this loading time It is taking >1min to fetch only 15 users.

Comment: Instead of storing the objectIds there I would store pointers to the users in the array, this is supported by Parse and should help

Comment: thanks for you reply.can you please give me some demo or link to understand your point clearly.

Comment: Simply create a column with type array (call it users for example) and store an array of user objects in it, that's it. When you fetch the object it should also return the user objects. Read through the documentation to get an overview of your options. https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#top